# Is a Model Driven Architecture in Language Oriented Programming (MPS) feasible at this time

Tags: paradigms, mdd, dsl

As a side project I am developing some sort of DSL where I describe a data model, and generate desired code files from it. I believe this is called [Model Driven Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-driven_architecture). My partial existing implementation uses C#, CodeDOM, XML and XSLT to do this manually.

I discovered there already exist better environments to do this in. The one which fascinated me the most is called [MPS](http://www.jetbrains.com/mps/), which follows the [Language Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language-oriented_programming) paradigm. [This article](http://www.onboard.jetbrains.com/is1/articles/04/10/lop/), written by a cofounder of JetBrains was a real eye opener for me. I truly believe LOP has a very good chance of becoming the next big programming paradigm once it has broader support. From my short experience with MPS, I noticed it is still mainly Java-oriented.

My question is, how feasible is it to generate code files for other (multiple) languages instead of just Java. I don't need full language support from the start, so preferably, I need to be able to implement a language in a agile way. E.g. first support only one type, add access modifiers, ...

Perhaps some other (free) environment already provides this out of the box.

P.S.:
I find it important to have a lot of control over the naming conventions and such of the generated code. This is one of the reasons why I started my own implementation.

UPDATE:

Judging from the answers it seems like people think I'm only interested in .NET solutions. This is not the case, any other suggestions are highly welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also think that Language Oriented Programming shows great promise, the possibilities look great and when you follow http://twitter.com/markusvoelter or read his blog http://voelterblog.blogspot.com/ you can see that it is pretty active.

For what I have seen so far it isn't production ripe yet even for Java development, the C# part is even less evolved. http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/282730;jsessionid=C5F9CBBD449C2DFAC390EC18B4B66863 and http://code.google.com/p/mps-csharp/

The C# projects show it is feasible, I don't think it will be easy. The integration with Visual Studio will be a problem.

As alternatives you could look into:

- [DslTools for vs2010](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DslTools)
- [UmlTools and extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/Video/ff859492)

End O Yes, there can be some confusion about the terminology:

MDA is an OMG standard for MDD. See [here](http://www.pathfindermda.com/sorting-out_prt1.pdf) for a nice explanation

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference between MDA and MDD.

Answer (score 1):

Any decent Lisp implementation will provide you with all the LOP tools out of box. Languages like Nemerle will do the job just fine too. And there are specialised DSL-building frameworks like [mbase](http://www.meta-alternative.net/mbase.html) or http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/ that can handle various target platforms.